# Exception when writing to the response output

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm getting the following exception when writing to the Response in a controller:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

System.NullReferenceException occurred
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=System.Web
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.Util.StringUtil.memcpyimpl(Byte* src, Byte* dest, Int32 len)
       at System.Web.Util.StringUtil.UnsafeStringCopy(String src, Int32 srcIndex, Char[] dest, Int32 destIndex, Int32 len)
       at System.Web.HttpWriter.Write(String s)
       at Controllers.DropboxController.<Sync>b__2(BlogUpdaterEventArgs args) in DropboxController.cs:line 78
  InnerException:
```

The line of code the exception is occurring on is:

```
BlogUpdater.Execute(htmlPostProvider, args => Response.Write(args.Message));
```

My *Execute* method posts messages as it's processing. The Execute method signature is:

```
public static void Execute(IHtmlPostProvider postProvider, BlogUpdaterEventHandler outputMessageCallback)
```

Sometimes this works, sometimes it throws the exception. When it has thrown the exception, nothing obvious is actually set to null when I inspect it in the debugger. The *args.Message* is a valid string, the response is valid, as is Response.OutputStream and Response.OutputStream.CanWrite.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: @Aristos No, it's a valid string (see my last paragraph ;))

Comment: Looks to me like what it's trying to copy the string to is null. So in this case it's the response, which is ultimately the address of `Byte* dest` in the call to `memcpyimpl()`. Brain dump: Does your application conditionally end the response early, do a redirect or call `Response.End()`? Could an exception be thrown elsewhere? Does `BlogUpdater.Execute` run in a new thread?

Comment: @greg84 When I've trapped the exception in the debugger (I have VS setup to catch all exceptions), it's on that line, so I don't think it's being thrown elsewhere. The Response isn't null, neither is Response.OutputString. Also Response.OutputStream.CanWrite is true. Nope, my application doesn't do a redirect or call Response.End(). BlogUpdater.Execute() doesn't run a new thread that I know of. It does call a couple of 3rd party libraries, but all calls to that event handler that writes to the response output are from the current thread.

Comment: Is VS set up to debug the .NET source? Might give you more of a clue. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/16/net-framework-library-source-code-now-available.aspx

Comment: I've just tried that and it let me view the source where the exception occurred, but I couldn't see the values of variables in the debugger, so it didn't give much away. I've just changed my code so that the event handler just appends to a StringBuilder instead, then writes the stringbuilder value to the response after my BlogUpdater.Execute() method has returned. This seems to have resolved the issue. Thanks for your help though.